# Horizontal CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to make a horizontal drop down menu in CSS. However, it appears vertically:
[image]

I want the two topmost menu items to be horizontal. What can I do, besides making a table with one row?

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">abc</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">abc</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try floating the list items:

```css
.root {
  overflow: hidden; /* clear float */
}
.root > li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="root">
  <li>
    <a href="#">abc</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">abc</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add submenu a class/id with
`.inline-menu{
        display: inline;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/fby9fan6/

Answer (score 0):

The gist of your question is actually this: what is the difference between *inline* and *block* elements? This is a fundamental question that is important to understanding the basics of layout in CSS/HTML. There is a good write-up on this topic and some of the trade-offs of the various approaches at:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Basically, <li> is block-level tag, meaning that it displays as its own "block" element: receives a layout (settable dimensions), by default takes the entire width of the parent element, and has a forced break after the rendered element (is on a line to itself).

So, that leaves us with a number of approaches for having your menu items sit side-by-side:

1. Use inline-level elements for your menu items
2. Use block-level elements and float them
3. Use block-level elements and style them as inline-block

All of these approaches are detailed in the above link. Personally, I prefer to use floated block elements. I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiralMichael/4rh5jow4/) with some rough css to give you an idea. Note that there are some considerations in how to display your submenus as well.  You'll note that I've implemented these as having *display: block*, with no float, because we want them to stack vertically.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">foo</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">subfoo1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">subfoo2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">bar</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">subbar1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">subbar2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.menu {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu > li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu li {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

ul.menu > li + li {
    border-left: solid black 2px;
}

ul.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.menu li a,ul.menu li a:link, ul.menu li a:hover, ul.menu li a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu{
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.submenu li {
    float:none;
    display: block;
}

ul.submenu > li + li {
    border-top: solid black 1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove some `<li>` tags:

```
<ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">abc</a>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">abc</a>
                    <a href="#">abc</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">abc</a>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">abc</a>
                    <a href="#">abc</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: This HTML is invalid. And doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Mmm. I just realized that I missed the part where specifies that "two topmost" entries are to be horizontal. Anyway, he already got an answer, so no need to bother anymore